# After submit: PHP Fatal error: Class not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php

[image]

When i execute URL http://localhost/debug/index.php, i see what i want. Then I press the button (submit) and I see this errors:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ClassB' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Debug\classA.php on line 2
>
> ( ! ) Error: Class 'ClassB'
>   not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Debug\classA.php on line 2

Please, can anybody tell me what is the best way how to reach ClassB in ClassA?

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once("ClassB.php");    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lískovec PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form action="classA.php" id="import_form" 
            method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
        <input id="submit" type="submit" 
               name="submit" value="submit" />
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

classB.php

```
<?php
  class ClassB {
    public $XXX = "1234567890";
  }
?>
```

classA.php

```
<?php
  $classB = new ClassB;
  echo $classB->XXX;
?>
```

Comment: You need to include the file classb into classa.php file

Comment: Is not a good practice to include or require files in one libraries storage? Index.php or bootstrap.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php suggest autoload as below 
In file class name and file name must same ...
When get instance object ,php auto include

classA.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{

    include "$class.php";

}


$classB = new ClassB;
 echo $classB->XXX;
```

classB.php

```
<?php
  class ClassB {
    public $XXX = "1234567890";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Is not a good practice to include or require files in one libraries storage? Index.php or bootstrap.php? Is it necessary to register it in every single php file over and over again? What if i had dozens of such a dependencies?

Comment: Standard psr-4 autoload .I can show you basicly ,if you make professional you are use PSR-4 autoload ...

Comment: With composer create psr-4 autoload